# Samsung j7 (2016) Beta Program

Tags: samsung, android-beta-program

I want to get Beta Updates. So i signup here http://static.samsungmembers.com/betatest/binary/nos/US/faq_sub.html with my Samsung account. But i can't find **Samsung Beta Program** App and **Samsung Members App** in play store. So i downloaded apk and install. But i am having service error in both apps. I am not sure my device and region are eligible for Beta Program. Or am i missing something? 
Is there any other way to get Beta Updates?

Comment: Available devices : Galaxy S7 / Galaxy S7 edge (with Sprint, T-Mobile, Verizon contract) You just answered your own question if you just read what is written in article

Comment: Agree with you!
Is there any way to get beta updates on my device samsung j7?

Comment: According to this your phone doesn't have beta updates, I doubt it get any system related updates, maybe quarterly.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung j7 is not eligible for Beta Program.
Available devices for Beta Program : Galaxy S7 / Galaxy S7 edge (with Sprint, T-Mobile, Verizon contract).